# Clickhouse. Get value from json

Tags: clickhouse

I use Clickhouse database. There is a table with string column (*data*). All rows contains data like:

```
'[{"a":23, "b":1}]'
'[{"a":7, "b":15}]'
```

I wanna get all values of key "b".

```
1
15
```

Next query:

```
Select JSONExtractInt('data', 0, 'b') from table
```

return 0 all time. How i can get values of key "b"?

Comment: Which language do you want to use?

Comment: I use sql. I tried extract value with function JSONExtractInt: JSONExtractInt('[{"a":1, "b":3}]', 0, 'b'), but it return 0

Comment: It would necessary what database you are using and what SQL you tried in the questions, so that people can understand your problem and help you solve the problem.

Comment: My mistake was wrong index. Index in clickhouse starting from 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT tupleElement(JSONExtract(j, 'Array(Tuple(a Int64, b Int64))'), 'b')[1] AS res
FROM
(
    SELECT '[{"a":23, "b":1}]' AS j
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '[{"a":7, "b":15}]'
)

┌─res─┐
│   1 │
└─────┘
┌─res─┐
│  15 │
└─────┘
```